# Clojure: How to get an exact answer in a function that calculates the average

Tags: function, clojure, clojure-core.logic

How do I get the exact answer instead of just the number / count

I can get the average of a list of numbers, but it will only add the total numbers and divide by the count

```
(defn aver
  [numbers]
    (if (empty? numbers)
      0
      (/ (reduce + numbers) (count numbers)))
      )
```

If I am to get the average of a list of [5 10] I'll not get the answer which should be 7.5, I'll only get the equation, how do I get otherwise?

```
 >(aver [5 10])
=> 15/2
```

Comment: That's not an equation, it is the textual representation of an exact fraction.  It _is_ a number as exact as you can expect.

Comment: See https://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Numbers especially the "contagion" part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer division in Clojure gives you rational numbers. If you want floating point numbers, one of the arguments needs to be a float. Or, you can pass the result to `float`.

`(float (aver [5 10]))`

`

Comment: OP requested "exact" ;)

Comment: Thanks Eric! Is there any chance you can pass that off in the function so you wouldn't have to use float in the REPL? I'm just experimenting at the moment

Comment: One option would be to provide an initial value (that is a float) to the `reduce` form, like this: `(/ (reduce + 0.0 nums) (count nums))` where `nums` is a collection of numbers (list, vector, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bicdec` to get a exact representation of that ratio.  E.g.

```clj
user=> (let [numbers [1 1 1 2]] (bigdec (/ (reduce + numbers) (count numbers))))
1.25M
```